# How to detect that Ctrl+R was pressed?

Tags: jquery, controls, keycode

I'm coding a function in jquery that executes if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is pressed but I can't seem to find out what the left and right ctrl keycodes are... Can someone please help?

UPDATE

```
    ///this works
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==17){alert("control was pressed")};
 });
```

Next Question--
How do I link control key press and another key press to execute a function?

```
  if(e.keyCode==17){llCtrlPress=1};
   if(e.keyCode==97 && llCtrlPress=1){DO SOMETHING}
  ????????????
```

That seems like it would work fine but then how do I set llCtrlpress back to '0' on keyup?

Comment: @sadmicrowave - I screwed up :( It should have been 17. I've corrected it now.

Comment: If you remove your original question, it won't be useful for future people, please leave your original question and then open a new question if you have another one.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have to use the **keydown** function to trap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> characters.  Here is my implementation of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
            alert('ctrl A');
        }
    });
```

Ctrl-R is tougher because in most browsers, that is **Reload Page**, which means the javascript doesn't run, the page is refreshed.

Just a note as well, the **keyCode** value are different in the keydown/keyupup functions than in the keypress functions.

**EDIT:** Removed ctrl variable, forgot about ctrlKey

Comment: That variable needs some serious closure

Comment: Didn't need the variable anyway, forgot about ctrlKey.  Thanks lincolnk and Josh.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is an entire list of keycodes that you can use.

Comment: Link is dead.  Updated resource?

Answer (score 5):

This is the code I'm using to disable refresh on IE and firefox (This works well for <kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    //this code handles the F5/Ctrl+F5/Ctrl+R
    document.onkeydown = checkKeycode
    function checkKeycode(e) {
        var keycode;
        if (window.event)
            keycode = window.event.keyCode;
        else if (e)
            keycode = e.which;

        // Mozilla firefox
        if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            if (keycode == 116 ||(e.ctrlKey && keycode == 82)) {
                if (e.preventDefault)
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        } 
        // IE
        else if ($.browser.msie) {
            if (keycode == 116 || (window.event.ctrlKey && keycode == 82)) {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
                window.event.keyCode = 0;
                window.status = "Refresh is disabled";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If you don't want to use useragent to detect what type of browser it is ($.browser uses navigator.userAgent to determine the platform), you can use

`if('MozBoxSizing' in document.documentElement.style)` - returns true for firefox

Comment: The user didn't ask to disable F5, so your answer (While helpful) doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Also, it's horrifying that you're trying to disable fundamental browser functions; whatever problem you're trying to solve, this is not the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a boolean property called [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Event.ctrlKey) that you should be able to use here...

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) { 
   alert("Ctrl is pressed: " + e.ctrlKey); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

why aren't you using `e.ctrlKey` ?

```
 if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
     alert('ctrl A');
 }
```

edit: here's an appropriate function to detect your ctrl-r keypress and stop the browser from reloading.

```
function keydown(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 82) {
        // 82 = r

        // TODO: your thing.

        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

i'm a jquery newbie, i think you'd do

```
$(document).keydown(keydown);
```

right?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).keyup(function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 81 && e.ctrlKey) { //CTRL+Q
             alert("CTRL+Q");
         } else if (e.keyCode == 27) { //ESCAPE
             alert("escape");
         } else if (e.keyCode == 67 && e.altKey) { // ALT+C
           alert("ALT+C");
        }     
    });
});
```

[key codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa243025%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

## Use `event.key` and modern JS!

```
$(document).keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.key === "r" && event.ctrlKey) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

or without jQuery:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function onEvent(event) {
    if (event.key === "r" && event.ctrlKey) {
        // Do something better
    }
});
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Answer (score 0):

The Key Code for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is `11`.

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) { 


  alert("Ctrl is pressed: " + e.ctrlKey); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Pure JavaScript and the [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)
- Support `metaKey`  for MAC
- Use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent reload

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
  if (ev.key === "r" && (ev.ctrlKey || ev.metaKey)) {
    ev.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser reload on CTRL+R
    console.log(ev.key);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {

   if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 82)
    {

    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

We can also use Ascii code for finding the characters as well as the characters

```
$('html').keydown(function (e) {
     keydownfunc(e);
});
function keydownfunc(e) {
   if (e.ctrlKey && (e.key === "r" || e.key === "R")) {
       alert("ctrl+R");
   }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. This duplicates many other answers. If you agree, please just delete it. (And ASCII is not involved with JavaScipt and HTML at all. See [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) ) If are interested in answering the newest JavaScript questions, try a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?tab=Newest) or tag subscription.