# jquery hotkeys and CTRL-C

Tags: jquery, hotkeys

I am building a webapp where a user can click on any cell in a table. On click, the text of that cell is copied and will pop up inside a disabled textarea in a fancybox, and the textarea is selected in js.  The user is then invited to hit CTRL-C to copy the text that is now inside the selected textarea.

I would like to combine 2 things together when CTRL-C happens:
(1) Copy the selected text
(2) Close the fancybox

I can trap the CTRL-C using jquery hotkeys, but once I use that to call the fancybox close method, the event is no longer propagating.  is there anyway to use both.  My code is:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+c', function(event){   
    $.fancybox.close(); // if this is commented out, CTRL-C works just fine
    return true;
});
```

I have explained numerous times how this question is different from the others. I indicated in my original question that I can detect the keystrokes. The problem was how to detect that, let the action continue and also to take another action.  I provided an answer below, which I figured out on my own.

Comment: Where do you expect the event to propagate to? In your code, it's already reaching the document object. Also, why include `return true;`?

Comment: I was hoping the "return true" would propagate the CTRL-C event after the fancybox was closed.  :)   Unfortunately, my knowledge of event handling in js is rather limited.  If there is another way to code this to achieve my goal, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

look at this solution from [How to detect that Ctrl+R was pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767126/how-to-detect-that-ctrlr-was-pressed)

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('ctrl A');
    }
});
```

Edit:

```
<textarea>test</textarea>
<p id="test"></p>

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey) {
        /* close fancybox here */

        $("#test").text("copied!"); /* optional */
    }
});
```

Comment: I am successfully detecting that CTRL-C has been pressed.  The issue is that I want the CTRL-C to continue, and copy the selected text, AND also to close the fancybox.  I am not sure how the CTRL+R thread helps with that.

Comment: I'm still not sure that I understand.  Your edited code appears to intercept the CTRL+C, then take the #test element and add the text "copied!" to it.  I am trying to take the pre-selected text from the #test element, copy it to the clipboard AND close the fancybox where the #test element is located.

Comment: I figured it out.  Instead of capturing the keydown, I capture the keyup.  The keydown copies the text to the clipboard.  The keyup closes the fancy box and  unbinds the CTRL+C capture.

Comment: Your comment helped me better than the answer @MarkSalamon thanks! +1 to your question