# Shortcut key(Alt+s or Alt+w etc) in html5

Tags: html

how to write code for shortcut key html5 like below image link.

http://screencast.com/t/iHOJqwy9

Comment: Sorry, but this question is not in a form considered on-topic here. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems a duplicate question but few possible solutions are:

[How to detect Ctrl+V, Ctrl+C using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903991/how-to-detect-ctrlv-ctrlc-using-javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var ctrlDown = false;
    var ctrlKey = 17, vKey = 86, cKey = 67;
$(document).keydown(function(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = true;
}).keyup(function(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = false;
});

$(".no-copy-paste").keydown(function(e)
{
    if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey || e.keyCode == cKey)) return false;
});
```

});

---

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+c', function(event){   
$.fancybox.close(); // if this is commented out, CTRL-C works just fine
return true;
```

});

---

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey) {
    /* do your stuff */

    $("#test").text("copied!"); /* optional */
}
```

});

### [jquery hotkeys and CTRL-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327724/jquery-hotkeys-and-ctrl-c)