# Able to detect Ctrl+R But stop reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, keycode

I am able to detect Ctrl+R but unable to stop reloading page.

Please help me to fix this.

I am using this code.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 65+17 && e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('ctrl R');
        exit;
        return ;
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767126/how-to-detect-that-ctrlr-was-pressed

Comment: I'm fairly confident that whether or not JavaScript can prevent a page reload depends on the browser's security policy.

Comment: Not all system key combinations can be managed in window. Try `return false` though or `e.preventDefault()`. not sure why you would only look for this way to reload. user can hit refresh button which you can't detect

Comment: I just want to make a shortcut to open my reports with `ctrl+r` but after pressing it reloading page, and I am using angular so I dont want reloading page here.

Comment: replace "return;"  to " return false;"

Comment: Still reloading page , @PawanLakhara

Comment: My question is different from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767126/how-to-detect-that-ctrlr-was-pressed , my issue is to stop reloading page.

Comment: post your  html page code.

Comment: I am using angularjs framework, many files are linked , but this code can be run on console I think, not ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(function () {
document.onkeydown = KeyPress;
function KeyPress(e) {
console.log(e);
      var press = window.event? event : e
      if (press.keyCode == 82 && press.ctrlKey) alert("Ctrl+R");  

     if ($.browser.mozilla) {
                if (e.ctrlKey && keycode == 82) {
                    if (e.preventDefault)
                    {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
            } 


if ($.browser.msie) {
            if (window.event.ctrlKey && press.keycode == 82) {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
                window.event.keyCode = 0;
                window.status = "Refresh is disabled";
            } 
}
}

});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
    <p>Click me away!</p>
    <p>Click me too!</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Brother , After detecting Ctrl+R it reloading page, which I want to fix.

Comment: I just check your code in jsfiddle you provided, And yes I am using jQuery also,

Comment: try now, mozila and ie are differents from google chrome

Comment: I did test to mozila because a dont have but i tested in ie and it is working

Answer (score 0):

The standard / clean way to help user prevent unwanted page reload is via [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) and *not* via overriding key event, which is, in fact, futile: you do not know what key combination invoked page reload (for instance, f5 works alike in most browsers), he may press CTRL+R with locationbar focused so your page gets no event to capture, he may have pressed toolbar button…

Mentioned standard approach from linked MDN page

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  var confirmationMessage = "\o/";

  e.returnValue = confirmationMessage;     // Gecko, Trident, Chrome 34+
  return confirmationMessage;              // Gecko, WebKit, Chrome <34
});
```

This will prompt user whenever he tries to reload / close / navigate away from your page no matter what initiated unload.